# Sql Server Sync Program

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I want to make a sync utility, I want to compare two databases and file the difference in each table and write in .sql file.

```
Done Till Now:
```

use TABLEDIFF.EXE  to compare databases and generate .sql file.

```
PROBLEM I FACED
```

1. some table not having primary key/unique key/guid/identity so how can i compare that.
2. can i manually provide unique key to tablediff for these tables. like table not having any key but i say take one column as unique key then my problem will resolved.

or suggest anything else.

Comment: Take a look at for example Red Gates compare tools

Comment: @PrateekGupta VisualStudio has option to compare two databases. It provides Schema as well as data compare options. and its really easy use.